# MySQL returning a total number of elements 18

Tags: php, mysql

I have a **directory listing** written in php & mysql and on sidebar I have 3 categories which sows sites from 3 different categories.

Or the first widget on my sidebar I have a query limited to 6 and so for the second and third. But on first widget returns only 3, so in second widget must be a query limited by 7 and on third 8.

How to do that automatically?

Thanks.

Comment: It'd be easier if you'd post a SCSE, but my guess is that you need to learn about the GROUP BY clause in SQL SELECT.

Comment: Or the first widget on my sidebar i have a query limited to 6 and so for the second and third. But on firs widget returns only 3, so in second widget must be a query limited by 7 and on third 8. How to do that automatically? Thanks.

Comment: To make it more specific. You have 3 queries (one for each category/widget), all 3 queries together should output 3 * 6 = 18 results. So if one query returns less, more results from the other queries should be used?

Comment: Yeees! This i want, sorry for my english. Thanks!!!